# how can I display text and date in one label in C# forms?

Tags: c#, forms, .net-4.8

The format would be : text + date(month) + text + date(year)

This is what I did so far. I know the "+" is incorrect, I just want to know how to write it

```
 lblMain.Text = "In " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString + " of " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString + ", the computer has detected that Ayesha is awesome. Is it possible that they are awesome?" ();
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: `ToShortDateString` is a method and should be called as such (e.g. `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()`). Also, you have a stray `()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Just write like this:

**String interpolation**

```cs
lblMain.text = $"In {DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")} of {DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")}, 
the computer has detected that Ayesha Mirza is awesome. Is it possible that they are awesome?";
```

Or

```cs
var text = "In "+ DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + " of " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy") + ", the computer has detected that Ayesha Mirza is awesome. Is it possible that they are awesome?";
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
label1.Text = string.Format("In {0}, of {1} , the computer has detected that Ayesha Mirza is awesome. Is it possible that they are awesome?", DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year);
```